# PDO not working in GoDaddy Server

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am working on a project that is using a GoDaddy private server. Looks like the project is using `mysql_connect` to connect to the db.

I have worked with PDO before and figured I would just create a new file within the server so I can connect by using PDO. However I can't get it to work, and I can't get any errors to show up, nothing seems to happen when I run this code.

If I try to echo out a string after that block of code, the string wont show up, if I echo out a string before this block of code, the string will show up.

If I try to execute a prepared statement nothing happens. PW, UN, HOST, and db name are all correct. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $dns = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mainsql;";
    $username = "bowski";
    $passwd = "kingsman1";
    try {
        $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $passwd);
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Where are your calls? you're showing the connection but not showing any results of the connections. All you have is `$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $passwd);` so its not going to do anything and only connect, Show how you are pulling your data from $db.

Comment: Try with `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: If your trying to pull errors you could do `$err = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`
and change `$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $passwd);` to `$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $passwd, $err);`

Comment: db variable declared as $dns and calling $dsn in db connection???? That will correct your problem.

Comment: Thanks rjdown, I added that and sure enough I got the error. Turns out the PDO module is not installed. Im having GoDaddy install it now. We are running PHP 5.4 I thought that came with PDO out the box.

Comment: Were they able to help you fix the issue? If so, would you mind sharing how they fixed it? (you can post an answer below and accept your own answer)

Comment: Can you please give some feedback, maybe a possible answer. I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: I had to have go daddy install PDO and make the PDO module active.

Comment: @eugensunic look at my answer, it might help you find out your problem as well.

Comment: @user2684521 pardon for the aditinoal disturbance, but how did you contact them and tell them to install PDO?

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ  thank you for your answer. This is the problem. I have to solve it now...

Comment: @eugensunic no problem dude, good luck with it.

Answer (score 5):

Some host providers or even your own server might have PDO disabled or not installed per default. GoDaddy is one such provider.

I often see people struggling in similar situations thinking their PDO code is wrong and asking the same question.

Therefore, it is always a good practice to check the availability of the PDO driver before checking the PDO code. One quick check is to perform the `phpinfo();` call which dumps a (long) table of installed components.

Even if you have PDO installed, this is to ensure and guarantee that the PDO driver is installed and running.

Add PDO driver checker code before your PDO code, saving you from some unnecessary debugging time:

```
if (!defined('PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME'))
    echo 'PDO driver unavailable';
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a step-by-step procedure to enable PDO extension on Godaddy:

1. Login to your CPanel
2. Go to `Web Hosting -> Manage` for your domain
3. Click on **Select PHP version** menu

[image]

4. Now, you have the option to choose PHP version from the dropdown. Choose a different version than selected (e.g. 5.4 or 5.5) and then click **Set as current**.
5. After that, check the checkboxes of PHP extension you want on your site (e.g. PDO) and then click **Save** button present at the bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have exact same situation as what you described. After a big while of confusion and debugging, and I found out the reason / solution. But still not sure why Godaddy PDO has this issue.

PHP v5.4.45

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:localhost;dbname=mydb', $user, $pass);

$sth = $pdo->prepare('select * from tab limit 1');
$sth->execute();
$row = $sth->fetchAll();
echo '<pre>select * from test -- not working -- ';
print_r($row);

$sth = $pdo->prepare('select now()');
$sth->execute();
$row = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo "\nselect now -- working -- ";
print_r($row);

$sth = $pdo->prepare('show databases');
$sth->execute();
$row = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo "\nshow databases -- working -- ";
print_r($row);

$sth = $pdo->prepare('show tables');
$sth->execute();
$row = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo "\nshow tables -- not working -- ";
print_r($row);

$sth = $pdo->prepare('show privileges');
$sth->execute();
$row = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo "\nshow privileges -- working but not right -- ";
print_r($row);

$sth = $pdo->prepare('select * from information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA != \'information_schema\'');
$sth->execute();
$row = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo "\nselect * from information_schema.TABLES -- working -- ";
print_r($row);
```

No error -- how confusing. And I test this, works:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:localhost;dbname=mydb', $user, $pass);

$sth = $pdo->prepare('select * from mydb.tab limit 1');
$sth->execute();
$row = $sth->fetchAll();
echo '<pre>select * from test -- working !!! -- ';
print_r($row);
```

And now I come up with this solution, but not sure if it is Godaddy PDO bug?

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:localhost', $user, $pass);

$sth = $pdo->prepare('use mydb');
$sth->execute();

$sth = $pdo->prepare('select * from tab limit 1');
$sth->execute();
$row = $sth->fetchAll();
echo '<pre>select * from test -- working !!! -- ';
print_r($row);
```

**Conclusion:**

It looks like Godaddy PDO does not use dbname, you need to manually run '**use dbname**' after **new PDO** and before any other SQLs